# Add a title to callOut view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I've created below view, where I want to add a title in the callOut, however I can't seem to figure out where and how to do it.  I want to add it to the annotations, which is in the `else if annotation.isKindOfClass(FBAnnotation)` statement

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var reuseId = ""

    if annotation.isKindOfClass(FBAnnotationCluster) {
        var reuseId = "Annonation"
        reuseId = "Cluster"
        var clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        clusterView = FBAnnotationClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        return clusterView

    } else if annotation.isKindOfClass(FBAnnotation) {

        let singleAnnotation = annotation as! FBAnnotation
        reuseId = "Pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        pinView = FBSingleClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId) as FBSingleClusterView
        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: singleAnnotation.imageString)


        pinView?.canShowCallout = false
        let imagePinView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(7.5, 7.5, pinView!.image!.size.width-15, pinView!.image!.size.width-15))
        imagePinView.clipsToBounds = true
        imagePinView.layer.cornerRadius = (pinView!.image!.size.width-15)/2
        imagePinView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imagePinView.image = UIImage(data: singleAnnotation.logoImage)
        pinView?.addSubview(imagePinView)




        return pinView
    } else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

**FBAnnotation**

```
class FBAnnotation : NSObject {

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var imageString = ""
    var logoImage = NSData()

}

extension FBAnnotation : MKAnnotation {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you set the canShowCallout to false. This should probably be true if you want a callout.

```
pinView?.canShowCallout = false
```

you also have to set the title property in MKAnnotation for it to show in the callout.

MKAnnotation protocol has a title but it's optional so you have to make sure it's implemented in your custom annotation

```
class FBAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var imageString = ""
    var logoImage = NSData()
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
}
```

or

```
class FBAnnotation : NSObject {

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var imageString = ""
    var logoImage = NSData()

}

extension FBAnnotation : MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?    
}
```

Comment: yes i know i need to set this to true, but in order to show it i need to add the title, but where i do this?

Comment: You add it to the annotation. Not the annotationView

Comment: `singleAnnotation` when i try to add title to it says it doesnt have any member named title

Comment: Well. I don't know what FBAnnotation is but the MKAnnotation protocol has a title property that should be set for display in callout.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/

Comment: i've added the FBAnnotation, any idea why it dosent have a member?

Comment: Maybe you can post that class and I can have a look. Does it implement MKAnnotation?

Comment: I updated the answer. The title and subtitle are optional and therefore you could compile without implementing them in your FBAnnotation. If you include them in your implementation you can set them and hopefully it will show in the call out